# Remove offset of CornerWidget in QMenuBar

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

How can I remove an offset of the top right corner widget in QMenuBar?

There is a code that I call in QMenuBar constructor:

```
auto buttons = new QWidget;
buttons->setStyleSheet("background:red;");

auto buttonsLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
buttonsLayout->setSpacing(0);
buttonsLayout->setMargin(0);

buttonsLayout.addWidget(new MinimizeButton());
buttonsLayout.addWidget(new MaximizeButton());
buttonsLayout.addWidget(new CloseButton());

buttons->setLayout(buttonsLayout);
setCornerWidget(buttons, Qt::TopRightCorner);
```

This is my result:

[image: QWidget in TopRight corner of QMenuBar widget]

I want that red area will be close to the right border.

Comment: Are you sure the border is actually part of the `QMenuBar` itself rather than part of the widget containing the `QMenuBar`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that grey part is QMenuBar widget.

Comment: In that case I can't reproduce the problem (Linux + Qt5.10.0).  It could be a style issue or you might want to try [`setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setContentsMargins) on the `QMenuBar` itself.

Comment: @Serbin How did you fix it?